# calculate the discount

Tags: sql

I have a customer discount table like these:
[image]

i have a deceared varialbe named @Total to store the total Amount

```
declare @Total numeric (12,2)

set @Total = (select Sum(LaborAmt) from #Data
              group by Co)
```

I need write a query to get the corrected discountRate according to the @Total. That is mean it should return 2 if my total amount is 3500000

```
SELECT     dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer, dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountRate
FROM         dbo.budCustDiscRate INNER JOIN
                  dbo.budCustomerDisc ON dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountID = dbo.budCustomerDisc.DiscountId AND dbo.budCustDiscRate.JBCo = dbo.budCustomerDisc.JBCo
WHERE     (dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer = 165) .........
```

sorry i just do not know have to write it

Comment: Post your table structure and desired results and we might be able to make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is that you are looking for it to return a value when @Total falls between BegBillAmt and EndBillAmt. You want it to return the correct DiscountRate. To do this we need either a BETWEEN statement, or two statements, one that checks BegBillAmt and one that checks EndBill Amt. I'll illustrate both:

First using BETWEEN:

```
 SELECT     dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer, dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountRate
 FROM         dbo.budCustDiscRate INNER JOIN
              dbo.budCustomerDisc ON dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountID = dbo.budCustomerDisc.DiscountId AND dbo.budCustDiscRate.JBCo = dbo.budCustomerDisc.JBCo

 WHERE (dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer = 165) AND @TOTAL BETWEEN BegBillAmt AND EndBillAmt
```

Sometimes BETWEEN is unclear (heck I'm not sure it's supported outside SQL Server, or in a case like there where they are database fields rather than static variables). So here it is with the two checks:

```
 SELECT     dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer, dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountRate
 FROM         dbo.budCustDiscRate INNER JOIN
              dbo.budCustomerDisc ON dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountID = dbo.budCustomerDisc.DiscountId AND dbo.budCustDiscRate.JBCo = dbo.budCustomerDisc.JBCo


 WHERE  (dbo.budCustomerDisc.Customer = 165) AND BegBillAmt >= @Total AND EndBillAmt <= @Total
```

Hope this helps clarify things for you.

Comment: I have four different discountRate, WITH DIFFERENT begbillAmt and EndBillAmt  The multi-part identifier "budCustomerDisc.Customer" could not be bound.

Comment: @user1723572 your inner join is incorrect or missing. I've updated my answer with the full query. Both of these should do what you need.

Comment: thanks you so much. it does work. today my mind just stop work. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    budCustomerDisc.Customer, budCustDiscRate.DiscountRate
FROM      budCustDiscRate 
INNER JOIN dbo.budCustomerDisc ON dbo.budCustDiscRate.DiscountID = dbo.budCustomerDisc.DiscountId AND dbo.budCustDiscRate.JBCo = dbo.budCustomerDisc.JBCo
WHERE     budCustomerDisc.Customer = 165 
             And BegBillAmt <= @Total
             And EndBillAmt >= @Total
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "budCustomerDisc.Customer" could not be bound.

Comment: @user1723572 note the different table names. This query is missing an inner join.